# Where can I find strong magnetic strips?

Tags: adhesive

How can I source strong magnetic strips? Preferably adhesive as well. Also, I need to be able to cut the strip into desirable lengths. If I could see the field strength rating that would be great, but if I can't I do need them to be really strong. Also, I require that the side of the magnetic strip facing me has only one pole pointing toward me.

Alternatively, I'm also open to the possibility of making one myself if it's cheap and can be done easily.

Note: I couldn't find any good tags for the post, so if anyone has any ideas (magnetic-strip?), please feel free to edit away!

Comment: This seems like a ["let's go shopping"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) question.  You might want to review [this post about 'shop for me' questions](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions/609#609) and see if you can reword it.  A quick google search yields lots of hits for strong magnets.  You'll need to explain why the google results are inadequate for you question to be accepted.

Comment: I tend to agree with the others that this is a shopping question, and borderline off topic for home improvement as a magnet question. You may have more luck talking about this in the chat room.

Comment: @alx9r A google search for magnetic strip yields results for strips with weak magnets, with the exception of a commercial provider which will consider end user requests individually. I am looking for strong magnetic strips, with the specs I have outlined, which I can't seem to find there.

Answer (score 2):

Lee Valley has [an amazing selection of magnets](http://www.leevalley.com/en/wood/page.aspx?cat=1&p=42363), typically rare-earth and very strong. Like "can lift 30 pounds" strong. They come in rods and discs, and come with steel accessories that make them stronger.

If it's really important to be a strip, [IKEA sells a knife strip](http://www.ikea.com/ca/en/catalog/products/20202083/). I own one of these; they screw to the wall and work wonderfully for holding a number of small kitchen knives. I can easily pull a knife off the strip so I am not sure if it would meet your "very strong" criteria.

Comment: Your Lee Valley link doesn't work; it just takes you to their search page

Comment: The results from searching for "magnet" are actually better, but I've put in a link to the category page since the search results don't seem to be linkable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kate. Though, I do need strips which I can cut into lengths as desired. Any idea where I can start?